# Why won't objects appear in my render?

Tags: rendering

I was making a scene and, due to the bad computer I'm making it on, I have to create the render every time instead of going into render view. Suddenly, the render only showed the background, and I tried to figure out why but all of the normal reasons why that would be the case weren't the case (i.e. hidden, in a different layer). I've only been using Blender for about a month, so please go easy on me. (If you'd like to include a critique of the water or plane/B24 liberator in your answer, please do!)

Before:
[image: Render before glitch]

After:
[image]
Render:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RqtMF7aQLyeFOmxrncZIgfk0pC-sNb0I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. The term 'normal reasons' is a little vague :) What's normal for one person might be very rare and unusual for someone else. Try attaching a link to your Blender file for an accurate diagnosis.

Comment: @OroNZ If you're going to ask for a blend file, please suggest the method the user should use to upload, ie. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , our preferred upload service.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot: Doesn't this warrant building a link to giantcowfilms into BSE's question UI?

Comment: @OroNZ I suspect if that were possible it would have already happened. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/where-is-the-include-your-blend-button and https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/suggesting-adding-a-button-link-for-uploading-blend-file-above-the-text-box

Answer (score 3):

You have your objects disabled for rendering

[image]

Comment: This question gets asked quite often. Please use the search box at the top.